# How do I combine string from one dataframe into one?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe column named 'fruit' that contains 5 unique strings and they occur multiple times within the rows in a .CSV file: redapple, orange, pear, grape, greenapple

Using lambda or maps, how would I combine redapple and greenapple together so that Python recognizes them as the same? Basically turning it from 5 into 4 unique strings: apple, orange, pear, grape

The reason I need to do this is because when I tried this line:

```
Df = pd.get_dummies(Df, drop_first=True)
```

I ran into an issue with a "dummy variable trap" where one of my unique pieces of string (redapple) was not being recognized in my correlation heat map that I created with sns.heatmap to do a linear regression.

If there is a better way than lambda or maps, I am open to that too. Thanks.

Comment: I guess it's not as simple as "red apple" or "green apple". What do your strings really look like?

Comment: It is exactly that simple, I just used fruits as examples to simplify the question.

Answer (score 2):

Create a dict of patterns to match fruits and replace them by the corresponding values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'fruit': ['redapple', 'orange', 'pear', 'grape', 'greenapple']})

d = {r'.*apple': 'apple'}

cats = pd.get_dummies(df['fruit'].replace(d, regex=True))
print(cats)

# Output:
   apple  grape  orange  pear
0      1      0       0     0
1      0      0       1     0
2      0      0       0     1
3      0      1       0     0
4      1      0       0     0
```